# JpaRepository can't find object with EmbeddedID

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to use a JpaRepository to get an object from the database by its ID and an having some trouble. It's an entity with an EmbeddedId.

I'm trying to get the object two different ways:

1. Using the named query (findById)
2. Using the method in SowServiceImpl

The exception I get when trying to get it using the named method is:

```
@Override
public SowDocument getById(int i) {
    SowDocument wow = sowRepository.findById(i);
    if (wow == null) {
        System.out.println("NULLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL");
        return null;
    } else {
        return wow;
    }
}

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist
...
...
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy791.findById(Unknown Source)
at com.**.pricing.web.services.impl.SowServiceImpl.getById(SowServiceImpl.java:61)
at com.**.pricing.web.controllers.UserController.getSowById(UserController.java:99)
```

And I get a NullPointerException when I try getting it using the EmbeddedId:

```
@Override
public SowDocument getById(int i) {
    SowDocumentPK peek = new SowDocumentPK();
    peek.setId(i);

    SowDocument wow = sowRepository.findOne(peek);
    if (wow == null) {
        System.out.println("NULLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL");
        return null;
    } else {
        return wow;
    }
}
```

Here's the object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SowDocument", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})})
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "SowDocument.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM SowDocument s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "SowDocument.findById", query = "SELECT s FROM SowDocument s WHERE s.sowDocumentPK.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "SowDocument.findByClientName", query = "SELECT s FROM SowDocument s WHERE s.clientName = :clientName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "SowDocument.findByCreationDate", query = "SELECT s FROM SowDocument s WHERE s.creationDate = :creationDate"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "SowDocument.findByDocumentCreator", query = "SELECT s FROM SowDocument s WHERE s.sowDocumentPK.documentCreator = :documentCreator"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "SowDocument.findBySowType", query = "SELECT s FROM SowDocument s WHERE s.sowType = :sowType")})
public class SowDocument implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected SowDocumentPK sowDocumentPK;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "clientName", length = 50)
    private String clientName;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "creationDate", length = 45)
    private String creationDate;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "data")
    private byte[] data;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "sowType", length = 45)
    private String sowType;
    @JoinColumn(name = "documentCreator", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private User user;

    public SowDocument() {
    }

    public SowDocument(SowDocumentPK sowDocumentPK) {
        this.sowDocumentPK = sowDocumentPK;
    }

    public SowDocument(int id, int documentCreator) {
        this.sowDocumentPK = new SowDocumentPK(id, documentCreator);
    }

    public SowDocumentPK getSowDocumentPK() {
        return sowDocumentPK;
    }

    public void setSowDocumentPK(SowDocumentPK sowDocumentPK) {
        this.sowDocumentPK = sowDocumentPK;
    }

    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }

    public void setClientName(String clientName) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }

    public String getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(String creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getSowType() {
        return sowType;
    }

    public void setSowType(String sowType) {
        this.sowType = sowType;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (sowDocumentPK != null ? sowDocumentPK.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof SowDocument)) {
            return false;
        }
        SowDocument other = (SowDocument) object;
        if ((this.sowDocumentPK == null && other.sowDocumentPK != null) || (this.sowDocumentPK != null && !this.sowDocumentPK.equals(other.sowDocumentPK))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

And here is its embedded ID:

```
@Embeddable
public class SowDocumentPK implements Serializable {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "documentCreator", nullable = false)
    private int documentCreator;

    public SowDocumentPK() {
    }

    public SowDocumentPK(int id, int documentCreator) {
        this.id = id;
        this.documentCreator = documentCreator;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getDocumentCreator() {
        return documentCreator;
    }

    public void setDocumentCreator(int documentCreator) {
        this.documentCreator = documentCreator;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (int) id;
        hash += (int) documentCreator;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof SowDocumentPK)) {
            return false;
        }
        SowDocumentPK other = (SowDocumentPK) object;
        if (this.id != other.id) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.documentCreator == other.documentCreator;
    }


}
```

Here's the code for the SowRepository:

```
public interface SowRepository extends JpaRepository<SowDocument, Serializable> {

    SowDocument findById(int i);

}
```

Here's the code for the SowService:

```
@Service
public class SowServiceImpl implements SowService {

    @Autowired
    private SowRepository sowRepository;

    @Override
    public void save(SowDocument sow) {
        sowRepository.save(sow);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<SowDocument> getAll() {
        return sowRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public SowDocument getById(int i) {
        SowDocumentPK peek = new SowDocumentPK();
        peek.setId(i);
        return sowRepository.findOne(i);
    }


}
```

My guess is that I somehow have the mapping(s) wrong between SowDocument/SowDocumentPK or am mis-understanding how to use the JpaRepository.

Comment: `ShowDocumentPK` has two fields but you create `SowDocumentPK peek = new SowDocumentPK(); peek.setId(i);` and pass as primary key. Is it deliberate?

Comment: Do I need to specify BOTH fields if I only want to get an object by its own ID, not the full composite?

Comment: I tried to explain how to use it in the answer below. See if it helps you; otherwise, leave me a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using SpringData JPA. If this is correct, look how the `CrudRepository` which is the super type of `JpaRepostory` Interface is defined:

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {
     ...
     T findOne(ID id);
     ...
}
```

And you are extending this interface as (btw you should have posted the implementation too):

```
public interface SowRepository extends JpaRepository<SowDocument, Serializable> {
    SowDocument findById(int i); 
}
```

The `findById(int i)` method is defined in **none** of the interfaces in the `JpaRepository` type hierarchy which means it is your own extension.

On the other hand you don't have an entity with a ID of type `int`. The type of the ID of your entity is defined to be of type `ShowDocumentPK` that consists of two fields.

So your repository definition should look like the following:

```
public interface SowRepository extends JpaRepository<SowDocument, ShowDocumentPK> {
     SowDocument findById(ShowDocumentPK id); 
}
```

And implement the method `findById()` by yourself (or use the official implementation class of the `JpaRepository`, i.e., `SimpleJpaRepository`).

And then you should create an instance of `ShowDocumentPK` and pass it to the `findById()` method, for example:

```
SowDocumentPK peek = new SowDocumentPK();
peek.setId(1);
peek.setDocumentCreator(100);

SowDocument wow = sowRepository.findById(peek);
```

In conclusion: your ID is not of type `int` and `findById(int)` is not the way how to implement in your case.

Hope this gives you an idea how to implement it correctly.

Comment: I actually did the findById by myself. I looked into CRUDRepository as you said too before you said it and found the same conclusion on my own 

Was able to work it now with a NamedQuery.

Comment: It's disgusting that a tool supposed to make you save time made me waste so much time. The primary key defined in `CrudRepository` was wrong in my case, still no compilation error and no runtime error, just zero results. Trying to debug I also let it print all the queries, and the printed queries were correct and working! I was getting crazy